# How to fix ClassCastException while processing a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm getting a `ClassCastException` while processing a JSONArray:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray
cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

I want to iterate over JSONObjects sequentially using a stream.

*My code:*

```java
JSONArray txnHashList = // intializing the JSONArray somehow

Iterable<JSONObject> jsonObject = IntStream
    .range(0,( (Map<Integer, String>) txnHashList).size())
    .mapToObj(i -> txnHashList.getJSONObject(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

How can I fix it

Comment: The exception message already tells you what to do: Do not cast your JSONArray to Map. Use the methods provided by class JSONArray for iterating its contents.

Answer (score 0):

To find the size of a JSONArray there's no need in casting it.

You can use method [`JSONArray.length()`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#length--) for that purpose.

Also, `Iterable` is not a particularly useful abstract type (. Using a `Set` would be more reasonable:

```
JSONArray txnHashList = // intializing JSONArray

Set<JSONObject> jsonObject = IntStream.range(0, txnHashList.length())
    .mapToObj(txnHashList::getJSONObject) // accessing JSONObject by index: i -> txnHashList.getJSONObject(i)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

**Note** that there are various cases in which [`JSONArray.getJSONObject()`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#getJSONObject-int-) would throw an Exception if the element under specified index is **not** `JSONObject`:

> **Throws:**
>
> `JSONException` - If there is no value for the index or if the value is
> not a `JSONObject`

Therefore, it would be safe to extract elements using [`JSONArray.get()`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONArray.html#get-int-) which returns a `java.lang.Object`, and then check whether it's a `JSONObject` and type-cast it only if that's the case (otherwise discard).

```
JSONArray txnHashList = // intializing JSONArray

Set<JSONObject> jsonObject = IntStream.range(0, txnHashList.length())
    .mapToObj(txnHashList::get) // accessing JSONObject by index: i -> txnHashList.get(i)
    .filter(e -> e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(JSONObject.class))
    .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But frankly saying I would not bother with streams. An enhanced `for`-loop (also known as "for-each") would be more suitable for such purpose (*remainder:* `JSONArray` *implements* `Iterable`):

```
JSONArray txnHashList = // intializing JSONArray

Set<JSONObject> jsonObject = new HashSet<>();
        
for (Object next: txnHashList) {
    if (next instanceof JSONObject e) {
        jsonObject.add(e);
    }
}
```

Where `next instanceof JSONObject e` is an example of Java 16 [*Pattern Matching for instanceof*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394).